# MongoDB elemMatch and text search

Tags: mongodb, search, text, mongodb-query

1) I'm running a find using elemMatch and it's working fine:

```
db.getCollection ('folders'). find (

{accessControlList: {'$ elemMatch': {user: '5500014VRN'}}}

)
```

2) I'm running a find using and and it's working fine:

```
db.getCollection ('folders'). find (

{'$ text': {'$ search': 'vitae'}}

)
```

I want to do a find where I can join find number 1 and number 2:

```
db.getCollection ('folders'). find
(
   [
      {
         "accessControlList": {
            "$ elemMatch": {
               "user": "5500014VRN"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$ text": {
            "$ search": "vitae"
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: error: {
"operationTime": Timestamp (1589335216, 1),
"ok": 0,
"errmsg": "Failed to parse: filter: [{accessControlList: {$ elemMatch: {user: \" 5500014VRN \ "}}}, {$ text: {$ search: \" vitae \ "}}]. 'filter 'field must be of BSON type object. ",
"code": 9,
"codeName": "FailedToParse",
"$ clusterTime": {
"clusterTime": Timestamp (1589335216, 1),
"signature": {
"hash": BinData (0, "mS + God8HgJpqS7I / rxmxUNjQu70 ="),
"keyId": NumberLong ("6782247565090881537")
}
}
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error :

> 'filter' field must be of BSON type object. "

You can find out that filter part/field of [.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) function must be an object. Syntax of `.find(filterObject, projectionObject)`. In contrast with `.find()` if you see [.aggregate([])](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html#aggregation-pipeline) you'll notice everything is wrapped in `[]` cause aggregation has stages those needs to be wrapped in an array - Which is called aggregation pipeline but `.find()` takes in objects `{}` with key/value pairs but not an array.

It has to be like this :

```
db.getCollection("folders").find({
  accessControlList: { "$elemMatch": { user: "5500014VRN" } },
  $text: { "$search": "vitae" }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining diference between find() and aggregate(). It works perfectly. Thank you